# Why is css not rendering from App.css file

Tags: reactjs

I dont know why this setup is not displaying the styles.

App.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Test Header</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
h1 {
    color: "red";
}
```

Directory Structure:

src/

- App.css
- App.js

The h1 element is not red. Why

Comment: Dear @Jim, Do you use CRA for this sample code?

Comment: yes, I believe it was used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple you used the string `"red"` instead of `red`. Try this instead:

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

That should work now.

Comment: Exactly right, you act like a tiger. nice, I leave an upvote for your high intelligence

Comment: No worries Jim! Happens to us all from time to time.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have red in quotes. Take off the quotes. Also, you don't need className="App". You actually don't have a css class called "App"., just an h1 {...;}.

This should work:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

```
<div>
    <h1>Test Header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it did save. and removing `className="App"` did not fix

Comment: Dear @Jim, Actually, using a useless class name doesn't cause to this issue. I think this issue is more than it appears. I guess it's from its configs.